# Netty UDP Performance Issue

Tags: java, performance, netty

I've implemented three small UDP server. One with a plain Java DatagramSocket (threaded), one with Netty and the last one also with Netty but with a threaded message handling (because Netty doesn't support multiple threads with UDP).

After some measurements I got the following results for requests per second:

- DatagramSocket ~30.000 requests/second
- Netty ~1.500 requests/second
- Netty (threaded): ~8.000 requests/second

The real application I have to implement must handle > 25.000 requests/second. So my question is if I make something wrong with Netty or if Netty is not designed to handle that much of connections per second?

**Here are the implementations**

DatagramSocket Main

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    final int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    final int threads = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    final int work = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

    DATAGRAM_SOCKET = new DatagramSocket(port);

    for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++) {
        new Thread(new Handler(work)).start();
    }
}
```

DatagramSocket Handler

```
private static final class Handler implements Runnable {
    private final int work;

    public Handler(int work) throws SocketException {
        this.work = work;
    }

    @Override 
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (!DATAGRAM_SOCKET.isClosed()) {
                final DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(new byte[1024], 1024);
                DATAGRAM_SOCKET.receive(receivePacket);
                final InetAddress ip = receivePacket.getAddress();
                final int port = receivePacket.getPort();
                final byte[] sendData = "Hey there".getBytes();
                Thread.sleep(RANDOM.nextInt(work));
                final DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, ip, port);
                DATAGRAM_SOCKET.send(sendPacket);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Netty Main

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    final int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    final int sleep = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

    final Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
    bootstrap.group(new NioEventLoopGroup());
    bootstrap.channel(NioDatagramChannel.class);
    bootstrap.handler(new MyNettyUdpHandler(sleep));
    bootstrap.bind(port).sync().channel().closeFuture().sync();
}
```

Netty Handler (threaded)

```
public class MyNettyUdpHandler extends MessageToMessageDecoder<DatagramPacket> {
    private final Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    private final int sleep;

    public MyNettyUdpHandler(int sleep) {
        this.sleep = sleep;
    }

    @Override
    protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext channelHandlerContext, DatagramPacket datagramPacket, List list) throws Exception {
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(sleep));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("ERROR while sleeping");
            }

            final ByteBuf buffer = Unpooled.buffer(64);
            buffer.writeBytes("Hey there".getBytes());
            channelHandlerContext.channel().writeAndFlush(new DatagramPacket(buffer, datagramPacket.sender()));
        }).start();
    }
}
```

The non threaded Netty Handler is the same but without the thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your Netty decode() method like so to make it equivalent to the DatagramSocket code:

```
@Override
protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext channelHandlerContext, DatagramPacket datagramPacket, List list) throws Exception {
  final Channel channel = channelHandlerContext.channel();
  channel.eventLoop().schedule(() -> {
    final ByteBuf buffer = Unpooled.buffer(64);
    buffer.writeBytes("Hey there".getBytes());
    channel.writeAndFlush(new DatagramPacket(buffer, datagramPacket.sender()));
  }, random.nextInt(sleep), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

But I'm guessing the sleep() code is simulating business code you will later execute.
If that is the case make sure you don't run blocking code inside the handler.

**EDIT:**

To answer your question below:
You got a bit confused with the channels. You create a pipeline in the bootstrap, and you bind to some port. The returned channel is the server channel. The channel in the handlers method (your decode method in your case), is like the socket you get when you `accept()` in traditional socket programming. Note that port you extracted from the incoming DatagramPacket - it's roughly the same. So you send data to the client back on this channel.

The code I wrote that schedules the response is simply doing the same as what your DatagramSocket code, and the threaded netty code you wrote.
I wasn't sure why you did that, and simply assumed you have a business requirement to delay the response.
If this isn't the case, you can remove the schedule call, and your code will run much faster.
If your business logic is non-blocking, and runs in a few millis, you're done. If it's blocking, you need to try to find a non-blocking alternative, or run it in an executor, i.e. not on the event loop.

Hope this helps, even though this wasn't part of your original question. Netty is awesome, and I hate seeing bad examples and bad vibes about it so it's worth my time I guess ;)

Comment: Thanks @EranHarel, I understood everything except one point ... how shall I know when I can write to the channel? In the DatagramSocket version it is simple, the receive method blocks as long as there is nothing to do. But what is the indicator in the channel that I have to write back the response?

Comment: Oh, I missed the point you're receiving data here. I'll write a more complete example later

Comment: Wow thanks, that did the trick! Now I reach the numbers of requests/second from the DatagramSocket implementation. But I am a bit confused. This feels a bit awkward. Is this the way Netty should be used? First I put my Decoder to the pipeline of the channel, then (in the Decoder) I get the channel (where I put my Decoder previously) and do something on its event loop. I can't really explain what I mean, but it feels awkward :D

Comment: I will answer above, cause it's harder to format text here. LMK, if you still don't understand later

Answer (score 0):

Creating a thread in every decode() is inefficient.
You can submit the task to `channel.eventLoop()` as Eran said if the task is simple and won't block(In fact `decode()` in `MesaggeToMessageDecoder`s is executed by the channel's `EventLoop`,so you need not submit it manually unless you want to shedule it).
Or you can submit the task to a `ThreadPoolExecutor` or `EventExecutorGroup`.
The latter is better because you can add listeners to the `Future` returned by `EventExecutorGroup.submit()` so you don't have to wait for the task to be completed.
My English is poor,hope these can help you.

Edit:
You can write as following,just executing the simple logic code in the `EventLoop`(ie.I/O thread):

```
@Override
protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext channelHandlerContext, DatagramPacket datagramPacket, List list) throws Exception {
        //do something simple with datagramPacket
        ...

        final ByteBuf buffer = Unpooled.buffer(64);
        buffer.writeBytes("Hey there".getBytes());
        channelHandlerContext.channel().writeAndFlush(new DatagramPacket(buffer, datagramPacket.sender()));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My business code that has to be executed is not very performance consuming. It takes just a couple of milliseconds. So where is the best place to execute it? `ChannelHandlerContext.eventLoop().schedule(...)`, `ChannelHandlerContext.executor().schedule(...)` or `ChannelHandlerContext. executor().parent().schedule(...)`. To get a `Future` is not really necessary for me.

Comment: I add some example code.You can get a complete example of UDP in netty from:https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/4.0/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/qotm

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. Thank you again for the example. The problem with the code you posted is, that only one thread is used because of UDP (NioDatagramChannel).